# String replace in right to left language (arabic)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on RTL functionalities. I am getting the string value from database as **(f1 (firstname**. But I want as **f1 (firstname)** here is my code for javascript. The below code was working perfectly EN language. It was not working only arabic language. Kindly give me suggestion.

```
getStringFromPattern : function(pattern, values) {
        var result = pattern;
        var len = values.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            result = result.replace('{' + i + '}', values[i])
            //alert(i);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Actually I am calling this function as

```
<p>
            ${getStringFromPattern(_i18n.getLabel("tx_plgt_pattern_BaggageMSC"), [filteredPolicies.list[0].airlineCode, getAirlineName(filteredPolicies.list[0].airlineCode)])}
        </p>
```

Kindly help me as expected result.

I am getting like this `(FI (fnameشركة الطيران الأكثر أهمية هي`

my expected result was `FI (fname)شركة الطيران الأكثر أهمية هي`

Comment: Could you show us a working call of your function for english language.

Comment: sorry I am not getting exactly what your are trying to say as per understand i am calling this getStringFromPattern like the below sentence

<p>
                ${getStringFromPattern(_i18n.getLabel("tx_plgt_pattern_BaggageMSC"), [filteredPolicies.list[0].airlineCode, getAirlineName(filteredPolicies.list[0].airlineCode)])}
            </p>

Comment: You should add the values of `pattern` and `values` used in your example in your post, what you expect exactly as result and explain what is wrong in your actual result (what do you mean with "not working") I guess a lot of SO users can't read arabic and can't tell what's wrong with your function.

Comment: I dont see any {0} or {1} in your pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to transform "(f1 (firstname" to f1 (firstname):

```
str.replace(/\(FI\s\(fname/,"FI (fname)");
```